# Restful services descriptor WADL or other way to identify method type?

Tags: rest, wadl

How can I identify a web service supports rest behavior or not? And if a service supports Rest then would that service expose any descriptor(e.g WADL) through which I can get method name, method parameters and method type (e.g. Get, put, post...)?

WSDL 2.0 supports Rest but currently no web service supporting it.

Thanks,
Asif

Answer (score 1):

if you use the HTTP OPTIONS method against an url, it should tell you what methods it supports.

Comment: I just have a URL of a web service which I will get at run time from user, so I have to implement a mechanism that can identify a web service protocols(e.g. SOAP, REST) which it support and make a request dynamically to call the service.

Comment: @Asif REST isn't a protocol, you can't detect it. You can detect SOAP by looking at the returned content type.